# How to Render Component Except for parent tag in Vue2

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

i want to make code more precisely. but i have no idea..

How to Render Component Except for `<span>` Tag Conditionally

In my case,

```
if(TrueCase)
{
  <span>
    <Component>
  </span>
}else{
  <Component>
}

In Vue
<span v-if:truecase>
 <component>
<span>
<component v-else>
```

I Think there is more precise code that i can`t think.

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: it's `v-if="truecase"`

Comment: Thank you @JaromandaX, but that code is not real.  
I want to know how to remove duplicated `<component>` 

Comment: So, what framework is the `if (TrueCase)` code - it also has "duplicated" component - by the way, while the `<component>` is duplicated in the HTML, it won't be duplicated in the page (DOM) - because of v-if/v-else

Answer (score -1):

I choose below code

```
<span v-if='truecase'>
 <component>
<span>
<component v-else>
```

As @Jaromanda says, `<component>` is not duplicated in HTML.
the reason why i ask this question is "Is it possible that only render parent tag without redering child component". but I think it is not a possible way.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).